# Is there any other way executeUpdate doesn't work properly?

Tags: grails, groovy

Method `executeUpdate` for limit type delete data, for example 250 data out of 1000 available. and this is not working properly, is this HQL not supported?

```
Subscriber.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM Subscriber WHERE date_created <= :minDate LIMIT 250")
```

Comment: what's the point in doing a paginated delete??

Comment: Does that even work?  How does pagination work when there's no sort?  I guess you're probably benefitting from some internal sorting native to the database.  That said, I'm with injecteer here...paginated delete is odd.  Is there some underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @injecteer I don't read it as wanting to use pagination with a delete.  I don't think any paging would happen. I read it as wanting to limit how many records are deleted, which I think is a different thing.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown haha, before editing it looked like a paginated delete

Comment: @injecteer I see that now.  Thank you.  The question was edited in a way that makes it a different question.  I had not looked at the history.